# How to get XML into a dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary

I have the following XML:

```
<Axis>
    <Collections>
        <Collection>
            <Client>
                <Name>Client 1</Name> 
                <Value>345</Value> 
            </Client>
        </Collection>
        <Collection>
            <Client>
                <Name>Client 1</Name> 
                <Value>4532</Value> 
            </Client>
        </Collection>
        <Collection>
            <Client>
                <Name>Client 1</Name> 
                <Value>235</Value> 
            </Client>
        </Collection>
        <Collection>
            <Client>
                <Name>Client 1</Name> 
                <Value>8756</Value> 
            </Client>
        </Collection>
        <Collection>
            <Client>
                <Name>Client 1</Name> 
                <Value>76</Value> 
            </Client>
        </Collection>
    </Collections>
    <Collections>
        <Collection>
            <Client>
                <Name>Client 2</Name> 
                <Value>56</Value> 
            </Client>
        </Collection>
        <Collection>
            <Client>
                <Name>Client 2</Name> 
                <Value>43</Value> 
            </Client>
        </Collection>
        <Collection>
            <Client>
                <Name>Client 2</Name> 
                <Value>34</Value> 
            </Client>
        </Collection>
        <Collection>
            <Client>
                <Name>Client 3</Name> 
                <Value>42</Value> 
            </Client>
        </Collection>
        <Collection>
            <Client>
                <Name>Client 3</Name> 
                <Value>23</Value> 
            </Client>
        </Collection>
    </Collections>
</Axis>
```

and I would like to store some of this in a dictionary `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` where the key is the name element and the value is a list of the Value elements.

I have mucked around with a bit of LINQ, but I have not been able to work out the dictionary part.

I have been able to get one element into a list:

```
myDoc.XPathSelectElements("//Axis/Collections/Collection/Client/Value")
     .Select(v => v.Value)
     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest:

- Not using XPath to select elements, but using the `Elements()` method (etc) instead
- Using a lookup instead of a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, via `ToLookup`. A lookup is like a dictionary with multiple values per key, but slightly simpler to handle (as it returns an empty sequence if you ask for a missing key) and much easier to construct.

So the code would look something like:

```
var lookup = doc.Root
                .Elements("Collections")
                .Elements("Collection")
                .Elements("Client")
                .ToLookup(x => (string) x.Element("Name"),
                          x => (string) x.Element("Value"));
```

You can then do things like:

```
foreach (var value in lookup["Client 1"])
{
    ...
}
```

An alternative to all the `Elements()` calls would be to use `Descendants()`, e.g.

```
var lookup = doc.Descendants("Client")
                .ToLookup(x => (string) x.Element("Name"),
                          x => (string) x.Element("Value"));
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a construct that allows you to query, my personal favourite for querying XML is Linq to XML.

- First, get what you're after (the name and value).
- Then, group that on the name
- Finally, project to your target type (a dictionary)

Example (you can copy and paste this straight into LinqPad):

```
var xml = @"<Axis>
<Collections>
   <Collection>
       <Client>
           <Name>Client 1</Name> 
           <Value>345</Value> 
       </Client>
   </Collection>
   <Collection>
       <Client>
           <Name>Client 1</Name> 
           <Value>4532</Value> 
       </Client>
   </Collection>
   <Collection>
       <Client>
           <Name>Client 1</Name> 
           <Value>235</Value> 
       </Client>
   </Collection>
   <Collection>
       <Client>
           <Name>Client 1</Name> 
           <Value>8756</Value> 
       </Client>
   </Collection>
   <Collection>
       <Client>
           <Name>Client 1</Name> 
           <Value>76</Value> 
       </Client>
   </Collection>
</Collections>
<Collections>
   <Collection>
       <Client>
           <Name>Client 2</Name> 
           <Value>56</Value> 
       </Client>
   </Collection>
   <Collection>
       <Client>
           <Name>Client 2</Name> 
           <Value>43</Value> 
       </Client>
   </Collection>
   <Collection>
       <Client>
           <Name>Client 2</Name> 
           <Value>34</Value> 
       </Client>
   </Collection>
   <Collection>
       <Client>
           <Name>Client 3</Name> 
           <Value>42</Value> 
       </Client>
   </Collection>
   <Collection>
       <Client>
           <Name>Client 3</Name> 
           <Value>23</Value> 
       </Client>
   </Collection>
</Collections>
</Axis>";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var dict = (from row in doc.Root.Descendants("Client")
            let name = row.Element("Name").Value
            let value = row.Element("Value").Value
            group value by name into grp
            select new { grp.Key, Values = grp.ToList() }).ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Values);
dict.Dump();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace XMLToDictionary
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var doc = XDocument.Load("c:\\Test.xml");

            var clients = doc.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "Client").ToList();
            Dictionary<string, List<string>> dic = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            foreach (var client in clients)
            {
                string key = client.Elements().First(e => e.Name.LocalName == "Name").Value;
                string val = client.Elements().First(e => e.Name.LocalName == "Value").Value;
                if (!dic.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    dic[key] = new List<string>();
                }
                dic[key].Add(val);
            }


        }
    }
}
```